# How can I show an INFOR form before an INputquery in Delphi XE6 for Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe6

I would like to show an INFO Form for 2 seconds before an InputQUery.
But it does not work. can anyone say why and what to do to make this?
Button2Click ís fired when the button is clicked.

```
 procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
    Tasktest: string;
 begin
  try
   DisplayMyForm(Sender,MPiFolge[1] ,'Bitte geben Sie den Meßpunkt '+MPlongName[MPFolge[1]]+'      ein!');
  except
   ShowMessage('test');
  end;

 end;

 (* This following  procedure does not show the INFOFORM before the InputQuery

 procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
    Tasktest: string;
 begin
  try
   DisplayMyForm(Sender,MPiFolge[1] ,'Bitte geben Sie den Meßpunkt '+MPlongName[MPFolge[1]]+' ein!');
   if InputQuery('TEST', 'Test', Tasktest) and (Tasktest.Trim <> '') then
   begin
     ShowMessage(' TEST');
   end;


  except
   ShowMessage('test');
  end;

 end;
 *)

 procedure TForm1.DisplayMyForm(Sender: TObject; MPNUmmer: integer; MsgText: string);
 begin
   //dlg := TFrmDisplayMPIN.Create(nil);
   Form1.Visible:=false;
   FrmDisplayMPIN.timer1.Enabled:=True;
   FrmDisplayMPIN.Caption:='Lokalisierung der Meßpunkte - Meßpunkteingabe für Meßpunkt: '+IntToStr(MPNummer);
   FrmDisplayMPIN.MsgTextLabel.text := MsgText;
   FrmDisplayMPIN.Show;
   //setfocused(FrmDisplayMPIN.Panel1);

 end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Application.ProcessMessages; Now it works.